# transform JSON settings file like web transform

Tags: c#, json, windows-services, config, t4

I am working on an application (windows service) that is to use a JSON settings file and was trying to work out the best way to handle the changes to the values in the settings for each of the environments the application will be applied to.

I was hoping to use a method like that used for app.config files (ie app.development.config, app.staging.config, app.production.config etc files exist with override values for entries in the base app.config).

I have found that Microsoft have a project on GitHub (https://github.com/Microsoft/json-document-transforms) which looks to be exactly what i am looking for however it does not really have much in the way of an explianation of how the transform is triggered.

I have added the nuget package to the solution and then added json files as dependent upon the main json file yet when i build there is no change to the json file. I cannot use the publish option since that will create a one click installer and i need it to just be a zipped package. Is there a trick i am missing with this?

Alternatively, has anyone used T4 templates to manage the config files for an application so as to end up with a config file per environment environment defined?

Comment: have you tried slow-cheetah? (https://github.com/Microsoft/slow-cheetah) I've used it for standard config files and it can do json config as well

Comment: thanks @Thundter that looks like what i was after ... will check it out